# Class 'Composer\InstalledVersions' not found , Composer require a PHP version ">= 8.1.0"

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, version, hosting

"php artisan queue:work" in the Hostinger SSH command line generates the error "Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.1.0". You are running 8.0.28." So, I ran "composer update", which generated this error "Class 'Composer\InstalledVersions' not found".

The command "composer update" generates this error for me: "Class 'Composer\InstalledVersions' not found", but I have composer version 2.0 and PHP 8.0.20. Normally, I want to add the command "php artisan queue:work" in the Hostinger SSH command line to manage the queues. However, this command generates the error "Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.1.0". You are running 8.0.28." So, I ran "composer update", which generated this error "Class 'Composer\InstalledVersions' not found".

Comment: `I have composer version 2.0` - there is no version 2.0 of Composer. Do you mean 2.0.0? That is really outdated, it was released in late 2020. Also, PHP 8.0.20 is also pretty outdated, it's more than a year old. PHP 8.0 will reach EOL in two months, so you should start updating your application to support 8.2 (or at least 8.1)